# How retrieve blocks for Guam?

Tags: census

Does anyone know how to retrieve this table in .text, .dbf or .csv format?
https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/tigerwebmain/Files/tab10/tigerweb_tab10_tabblock_2010_gu_010.html

I can't find the way to retrieve it.

Comment: Not about GIS... But what about copy-paste to a text editor ? Works for me... I get a tab-separated (C)SV.

Comment: This problem isn't related to GIS, is HTML code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to that website.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
4. Open a text editor (notepad++ should work)
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
6. Remove the header line (until MTFCC)
7. Save as any_filename.csv

You will have a tab-separated (C)SV that you can import in QGIS or Excel/Calc, etc.

(Tested with Firefox and Geany)

Comment: Before I saw your answer I realized it was such a simple 'problem' (:facepalm).